# How do I enable PvP in Worldguard Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was making a PvP Area on my survival server, but players can not hurt other players.

How do I enable Player versus Player?

Comment: "Worldguard"? Do you mean "spawn protection"? Or is this a mod? If yes, please at least link to a relevant page explaining it.

Comment: There is [a plugin named WorldGuard](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldguard), which could be what the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

OPs **can** hurt OPs.

Most probably, the PvP flag in the server config is turned off, or you both are in Creative- you should both switch to Survival.

If the PvP flag is turned off, you should open `server.properties` and replace `pvp=false` to `pvp=true` and restart the server.

If you are in Creative, you should both run the command `/gamemode 0` to switch to Survival.

If your server uses plugins, you should try disabling them, or running another server using the vanilla server files.